# Which is correct here, “your” or “yours”?

Tags: adjectives, pronouns

You and she have finished {your/yours} work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct word in the context you have given is

> your

e.g.

> You and she have finished **your** work?

Answer (score 0):

The grammatically correct question is:

'Have you both finished your work?'

Including 'and she' sounds strange.

As about 'yours' it can't be used before nouns.

***YOURS*** is a pronoun and functions as the subject or nominative provocative of the sentence.

For example:
'Is this her work?' 
- 'No, it's ***yours***.'